# HttpContext.Current.Session unclear behaviour boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, httpcontext, conditional-operator

I'm having a weird behaviour trying to get the value of a boolean property stored at [HttpContext.Current.Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx).

The object is a boolean. First I'm trying to check if the object exists and, if exists, use it.

I'm trying to use it in a `?:` operator but it behaves strange. Here is my Watch window:
[image: Watchers from VisualStudio]

### Premise

- The `"ExistingKey"` key exists and has a value of false (if key
  doesn't exists returns false).

### Results

1. When checking if `!=null` it returns false (first thing weird).
2. When using the `?:` operator, besides the condition is false, it returns the first expression, 4 (second thing weird).

Could somebody explain this behaviour?

---

*Note: I'm not asking for an alternative to bypass this situation. Just asking why this works like this.*

Comment: Well, I tested it and `HttpContext.Current.Session["ExistingKey"] != null` actually returns true. I'm also curious about this behavior.

Comment: It looks correct to me. ExistingKey has a value; it isn't null. And all of your comparisons reflect that. So what is the issue?

Comment: @JeffSiver `HttpContext.Current.Session["ExistingKey"] != null` returns false but it should be true instead. In my test, it was true as well btw. I suspect it's something related with the current context but just can't confirm. Maybe someone who experienced the issue before can help

Comment: @uteist, I'm confused with your watch window. The last two items, with the ? 4 : 5 are correct. Is there a typo in the third item that is making it display differently?

Comment: It's not my watch window, it's Mario's. I tested it myself as well, and probably you and I have same results. His, though, is different..

Comment: @GiladGreen - Why is line 4 incorrect? The only one that doesn't fit is line 3. All the other ones are consistant.

Comment: Could there be an invisible character in line 3? Or a wrong character? Do you get the same result if you retype that line?

Comment: Yeah, line 4 is actually correct. It's just inconsistent with line 3 which, I believe, is the problematic one.

Comment: My understanding is : 1) Session["ExistingKey"] holds false so it is not null. At ITEM 4 when we say if it not null 4 is assigned to it . SO at Item 5 when we say == null  , since Session["ExistingKey"] hold 4 now the condition is false and 5 gets assigned.

Comment: Try and see if you can reproduce this problem in code instead of watch window. Watch window can produce false type comparison result especially when its an object

Comment: place a breakpoint in session[index] indexer and check if some one else is changing it.

Comment: Boolean seems to be a special beast, this does work though: bool test = Session["ExistingKey"] != null. It does work as expected with other value types.

Comment: Added to my last comment, it does work with Session["ExitingKey"] = true. Maybe the disctinction between an object, in this case a non-nullable value type, with value false and null is a bridge too far for the runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be some sort of bug within the watch window. I tested the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var  objDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var boolDict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    Session["ExistingValue"] = false;
    bool? nullableValue = false;

    Session["ExistingValueNullable"] = nullableValue;
    var existingValue = (bool)Session["ExistingValue"];
    var existingValueIsNotNull = Session["existingValue"] != null;
    objDict["ExistingValue"] = false;
    boolDict["ExistingValue"] = false;
    bool existingValueIsNotNullIf = false;
    if (Session["ExistingValue"] != null)
    {
        existingValueIsNotNullIf = true;
    }
}
```

And I got the following in the watch window:

[image: Watch Window]

So you can see that in the case of Session and a Dictionary<string,object> the != null evaluates to false. A Dictionary<string,bool> evaluates this comparison properly.

Weirdly, 'Session["ExistingValue"] != null' and 'Session["ExistingValue"]' == null' are both false.

If I cast the session value to a bool first then compare to null, I get the correct result.

Finally, if I test the value 'Session["ExistingValue"] != null' in code, I get a proper result. Which at least reassures me that this is something in the watch window, and there shouldn't be a similar issue in code.

All my testing was in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not consider this an answer at the moment, the following is much easier to write in an answer than in a comment due to space and formatting constraints.

I agree with the comments on the question, line 3 is not consistent with the results of the other lines. The only thing I can think of that could explain this is that the Watch window in Visual Studio has stale data / has a corrupted state. I think executing the same statements but in the code itself could prove or refute this. The following code is the same as what you have but output to a `StringBuilder`. Could you execute this and post the resulting string and let us know if this is any different from what you have in your Watch window?

```
var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

builder.AppendFormat("session[\"someKeyThatDoesNotExist\"] => value {0}", session["someKeyThatDoesNotExist"] ?? "null").AppendLine();
builder.AppendFormat("session[\"ExistingKey\"] => value {0}", session["ExistingKey"] ?? "null").AppendLine();
builder.AppendFormat("session[\"ExistingKey\"] != null => value {0}", session["ExistingKey"] != null).AppendLine();
builder.AppendFormat("session[\"ExistingKey\"] != null ? 4 : 5 => value {0}", session["ExistingKey"] != null ? 4 : 5).AppendLine();
builder.AppendFormat("session[\"ExistingKey\"] == null ? 4 : 5 => value {0}", session["ExistingKey"] == null ? 4 : 5).AppendLine();

var totalDebugInfo = builder.ToString();
```